# Represent $\frac{1}{3} \ln(x+2)^3 + \frac{1}{2}[\ln x - \ln (x^2+3x+2)^2]$ as a single logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having some trouble trying to find the single logarithm for the following:

$$\frac{1}{3} \ln(x+2)^3 + \frac{1}{2}[\ln x - \ln (x^2+3x+2)^2]$$

I understand that I have to use the addition and subtraction rules but the coefficients are confusing me. These are some of the steps I took:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3} \ln(x+2)^3 + \frac{1}{2} [\ln \frac{x}{(x^2+3x+2)^2}]
\end{align}$$

Now from here, if I used the addition rule then what would happen to the coefficients? and also, is there a way for me to simplify the powers $2$ and $3$?

Hints would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{3} \ln(x+2)^3 + \frac{1}{2}[\ln x - \ln (x^2+3x+2)^2]$$

$$=\ln(x+2)+\frac{1}{2} \ln(x)-\ln(x^2+3x+2)$$

$$=\ln\frac{(x+2)(\sqrt x)}{x^2+3x+2}$$

$$=\ln \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}$$

Properties of $\ln(x)$ that have been used :

$$a \ln(b)= \ln (b^a), ln(a)+ln(b)=\ln(ab)$$

Comment: please see that this is not complete yet...

Comment: Can you please explain where the power of two went? I understand that $\frac{1}{2}\ln x$ became $\ln \sqrt{x}$ but what about $\ln (x^2+3x+2)^2$? How did that just become $x^2+3x+2$?

Comment: you do have $\frac{1}{2} \ln(x^2+3x+2)^2$...

Comment: But the $\frac{1}{2}$ is not distributed is it? So how can it apply to both $\ln x$ and $\ln (x^2+3x+2)$?

Comment: It is distributed.... You have  $\frac{1}{2}[\ln x - \ln (x^2+3x+2)^2]$ Right????

Comment: ahh! Silly me, I forgot the original question :) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It is alright.... please be careful from next time...

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik $\ln a\ln b\neq\ln(a+b)$

Comment: @AdiDani : error corrected.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $a\ln b=\ln b^a$, $\ln a + \ln b = \ln ab$, $x^2+3x+2=(x+1)(x+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $$ b \cdot \log a = \log a^b$$